# Sorting MongoDB aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregate

I am trying to sort data from collection. I am able to sort with number and boolean. In my case I want to sort with parameter which seems like integer but it is saved as string in database.

Note: I cannot change **ItemRef** to integer datatype in database.

Data in mongo collection:

```
{
    "_id":ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e80"),
    "UserId":ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e06"),
    "ItemRef":"AA008",
    "Name":"Sample12"
},
{
    "_id":ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e95"),
    "UserId":ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e06"),
    "ItemRef":"560",
    "Name":"Sample"
},
{
    "_id":ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e90"),
    "UserId":ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e06"),
    "ItemRef":"5010",
    "Name":"Sample1"
},
{
    "_id":ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e91"),
    "UserId":ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e06"),
    "ItemRef":"5060",
    "Name":"Sample2"
},
{
    "_id":ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e92"),
    "UserId":ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e06"),
    "ItemRef":"1080",
    "Name":"Sample4"
}
```

Query:

```
 db.parrot.users.aggregate([
         {$match:{ "UserId" : ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e06")},
         {$sort:{"ItemRef":1}}
 ])
```

It is not sorting with **ItemRef**

Expected Result:

```
{
    "_id":ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e95"),
    "UserId":ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e06"),
    "ItemRef":"560",
    "Name":"Sample"
},
{
    "_id":ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e92"),
    "UserId":ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e06"),
    "ItemRef":"1080",
    "Name":"Sample4"
}
{
    "_id":ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e90"),
    "UserId":ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e06"),
    "ItemRef":"5010",
    "Name":"Sample1"
},
{
    "_id":ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e91"),
    "UserId":ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e06"),
    "ItemRef":"5060",
    "Name":"Sample2"
},
{
    "_id":ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e80"),
    "UserId":ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e06"),
    "ItemRef":"AA008",
    "Name":"Sample12"
}
```

Comment: So you cannot change itemRef to integer. Can you add it as another field as integer for sorting?

Comment: **ItemRef** might have string value as well, like _{"ItemRef":"AA008"}_

Comment: It can be both integer or string you are saying. And you don't want it to be sorted as string. Then what do you want exactly? Where should it be a document with itemRef : "A2000" in your example?

Comment: I updated the document list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**- if you need Result so try this Query**

```
db.parrot.aggregate([
         {$match:{ "UserId" : ObjectId("56ccd6b5267ecf0528008e06")}},
         {$sort:{"ItemRef":1}}
 ],{ collation: { locale: "en_US", numericOrdering: true } });
```

Answer (score 0):

Zero padding can solve problem. For example store 560 as 0560 . But it is still hack. I don't think mongo can sort it as number if it is stored as string.